# Android studio Fragment onAttach. What happens in onAttach?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have been learning about fragments in android studio. 
Here is what I have been reading
[Click](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)
 and [Click.](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

I writed this simple code. When you click a button in a fragment (frag.xml) then text appears (activity_main.xml). Code works fine but I cannot understand what happens in onAttach. Can some explain this onAttach code in a simple way? I get the trycatch and sout message but otherwise I am lost.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    try{
        st =(setText) context;
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Virhe " + e);
    }
}
```

Here is the rest of the code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


public class interExample extends Fragment {

setText st;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag,container,false);
    Button bt =(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            st.text("fragone pressed");
        }
    });
    return view;
}




public interface setText{
    void text(String text);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    try{
        st =(setText) context;
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Virhe " + e);
    }
}
```

Here is MainActivity

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements interExample.setText{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Fragment f1 = new interExample();
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.line1,f1);
    ft.commit();
}


@Override
public void text(String t){
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    tv.setText(t);
}}
```

Thank you for the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that your `MainActivity` implement `interExample.setText` which is an interface you define in your fragment. 
This mean your `MainActivity` will implement the method inside `setText` interface (define what they do).

Now let's straight to your main question about the `onAttach()`, this method is called first time a fragment is called. (take a look at fragment lifecycle)

in this `onAttach()` there are code like

```
try{
   st =(setText) context;
}catch (Exception e){
   System.out.println("Virhe " + e);
}
```

here the code is trying to say that we are passing the `context` to `st`

to further simplified it would be to pass whichever activity is calling this fragment (`context` since Activity is a context) to `st`
`MainActivity` is calling this fragment so `MainActivity` is `st` here.

note: the (`setText`) is just casting the `context` to `setText` so that here the activity will act as `setText`.

So then we could execute method ini `MainActivity` by using`st`, because we already implement them in the `MainActivity`